# How database data can be updated by id - Django

Tags: django, django-models, auto-update

Hi guys im new in django and I want to update my database.
I have my form and my model that create correctly all the data in my database.

When this was created the performance field gets default value 0 and the created field gets the creation date.
Everything up to this moment is perfect.

I have this model and this view:

**models.py**

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class Model(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    performance = models.FloatField(default=0)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, null=True)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['-created']
```

**views.py**

```
def form_x(request):
     user = request.user
     form = XForm(request.POST or None)
     if form.is_valid():
         performance = form_data.get('performance')
         obj = Model.objects.create(user=user,
                                    performance=performance,)
         return redirect('form')
    else:
         form = TForm()
    return render(request, 'funciones/btc.html', {'form':form})
```

**My question:**

How can i update the ***performance*** field searching by ***id***, AUTOMATICALLY after 1 min
once the POST request has been sent?

i dont know whats better if use a function update view or a Class Update View

What you recommend?

Thank you so much!

Comment: Can you be more specific what you want to do?